# Simple try catch looping solution for c++

Tags: c++, try-catch, gnu

I can't see why this fails. Why does it loop forever after throwing the error?

```
bool undone;
do
{
    undone = false;
    try
    {
        o.spr(); // function throwing error E object 
    }
    catch(E &r)
    {
        undone = true;
        cout << r.reason << endl;
    }
}
while(undone);
```

Here is the function:

```
void spr()
{
    E r;
    int n;
    cout << " put n : "<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        r.reason="fail !!";
        throw r;
    }
    cout << " your n is : "<< n;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `o.spr()` throws every time you call it.

Comment: Nope , it works nicely for good input .

Comment: Then you have bad input.

Comment: I think you're gonna need `cin.clear()` after it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is recovering after the error.

First you have to clear the error flag from `cin` using `cin.clear()`. Then you have to read the bad input so it doesn't cause an error next time:

```
void spr()
{
    E r;
    int n;
    cout << " put n : "<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear(); // clear the error flag

        std::string bad_input;
        cin >> bad_input; // skip over bad input

        // now it is safe to re-use cin

        r.reason="fail !!";
        throw r;
    }
    cout << " your n is : "<< n;
}
```

Probably a better way to skip the bad input:

```
void spr()
{
    E r;
    int n;
    cout << " put n : "<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear(); // clear the error flag
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip over bad input

        r.reason="fail !!";
        throw r;
    }
    cout << " your n is : "<< n;
}
```

The `cin.ignore()` function skips over the maximum possible number of input characters until it gets to an end of line `'\n'` character.

Answer (score -1):

In case `o.spr()` throws, you set `undone` to `true`. Then condition in `while()` is checked, and it's `true`, so it loops, tries to call `o.spr()` again, and so on... Reconsider your `undone` flag and its value.

Comment: But there is again undone=false ; at the begining of the  loop. Doesn't it change everything

Comment: And it will remain `false` only if `o.spr()` does not throw an error. It seems that it does throw every time, though. Is it not the case?

Comment: void spr (){

           E r;
            int n;
          cout << " put n : "<<endl;
        cin >> n ;
          if (cin.fail()){
          r.powod="fail !!";
         throw r ;}
        cout << " your n is  : "<< n ;
          }

Comment: should ask me again for n ?

Comment: Oh, obviously. Galik's anwers's the correct one. I totally missed it, and should have asked you for your input first.